# Java new line after 80 char input

Tags: java, email, word-wrap

i'am making a simple text editor in java. 
In this connection, I am looking for a function that wraps a given string input after a number of characters.

For example, wrap after 10 chars on the given input:

input:
qwertyuiopasdfghjkløæ

Output:
qwertyuiop\n"
asdfghjklø\n"
æ\n"

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for a function that takes a String as input and list of String (max length of 80 characters) as output?

Comment: Or are you looking for something that will *display* the text in line-wrapped form?  If so, how / where are you displaying it?

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you want to do.  It's pretty simple to write methods to insert newline characters into a string, or to break a string up into a list of strings, etc., but you've only given us a vague general question and we can't do anything with it.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. 
i want to wrap the string input after a number of characters. 

For example, wrap after 10 chars on the given input:

input:
qwertyuiopasdfghjkløæ


Output:
qwertyuiop\n
asdfghjklø\n
æ\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wrap the lines at word boundaries (whitespace), [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) has the class [**`org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils`**](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html), which has the methods:

```
public static String wrap(String str, int wrapLength)

public static String wrap(String str, int wrapLength, String newLineStr, boolean wrapLongWords)
```

<sup>** You can download the library from [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22commons-lang3%22).*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex:

```
String wrapped = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\G.{80})", "\n");
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Seems to work well as long as you do not use space. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: @spelly be specific. What edge cases do you have? Add sample input and desired output (assume breaks say every 10 chars for the purposes of illustration so the examples aren't enormous)